# Why does net_kernel:monitor_nodes/2 not deliver nodeup/nodedown messages for sname nodes?

Tags: erlang, distributed-system

I start up a master node with a short name and get it running a process to monitor for node up and down messages.

```
> erl -sname master -cookie monster
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.9.3  (abort with ^G)
(master@pencil)1> c("/tmp/monitor.erl").
{ok,monitor}
(master@pencil)2> Pid = monitor:start().
<0.44.0>
(master@pencil)3> Pid ! running.
RECV :: running
running
(master@pencil)4> net_adm:names().
{ok,[{"master",52564}]}
```

At this point only the `master` node is running. I startup the second node on the same machine:

```
> erl -sname client -cookie monster
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.9.3  (abort with ^G)
(client@pencil)1>
```

and wait for a minute, just incase I'm reading the docs wrong and there's a complication with the net tickrate. Nothing, so on master I force the connection:

```
(master@pencil)5> net_adm:names().
{ok,[{"master",52564},{"client",52579}]}
(master@pencil)6>
```

and nothing from my little monitor process. Now, if I do the *same* thing but use long names--that is `-name`--this works just fine. I'm surprised, though, as the `net_kernel` docs don't mention that. What's the deal?

---

Here's the `monitor.erl` referenced above:

```
-module(monitor).

-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    spawn_link(fun init_loop/0).

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal Functions
%%%===================================================================

init_loop() ->
    net_kernel:monitor_nodes(true, []),
    loop().

loop() ->
    receive
    Msg -> io:format(user, "RECV :: ~p~n", [Msg])
    end,
    loop().
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`net_kernel:monitor_nodes/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#monitor_nodes-1) **definitely does** deliver nodeup/nodedown messages for nodes with either short and long names.

However, the `nodeup` message is only delivered when the node is connected, as mentioned in the documentation. Why you got the `nodeup` message with `-name` is a mystery (and couldn't be reproduced here) as `net_adm:names/0` does not connect nodes at all. It only connects to epmd to obtain the list of locally registered nodes. It will even list nodes with a different cookie.

If you connect the client to the master (or the other way around) with `net_adm:ping/1` (or an `rpc` call), the monitoring process will receive the `nodeup` message.